# Firebase - Send notification using PHP not working

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently following the tutorial from this website:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I am able to send notification from the firebase console but failed to do so from PHP.

config_firebase.php

```
<?php

 // Firebase API Key
define('FIREBASE_API_KEY', 'xxx');

?>
```

push_firebase.php

```
<?php 
class Push {

    // push message title
    private $title;
    private $message;
    private $image;
    // push message payload
    private $data;
    // flag indicating whether to show the push
    // notification or not
    // this flag will be useful when perform some opertation
    // in background when push is recevied
    private $is_background;

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setMessage($message) {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function setImage($imageUrl) {
        $this->image = $imageUrl;
    }

    public function setPayload($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setIsBackground($is_background) {
        $this->is_background = $is_background;
    }

    public function getPush() {
        $res = array();
        $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
        $res['data']['is_background'] = $this->is_background;
        $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
        $res['data']['image'] = $this->image;
        $res['data']['payload'] = $this->data;
        $res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        return $res;
    }

}



?>
```

firebase.php

```
<?php
class Firebase {

    // sending push message to single user by firebase reg id
    public function send($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // Sending message to a topic by topic name
    public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // sending push message to multiple users by firebase registration ids
    public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // function makes curl request to firebase servers
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/config_firebase.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

push_notification_firebase.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AndroidHive | Firebase Cloud Messaging</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.gstatic.com/mobilesdk/160503_mobilesdk/logo/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
            }
            div.container{
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
            }
            legend{
                font-size: 30px;
                color: #555;
            }
            .btn_send{
                background: #00bcd4;
            }
            label{
                margin:10px 0px !important;
            }
            textarea{
                resize: none !important;
            }
            .fl_window{
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top:100px;
            }
            pre, code {
                padding:10px 0px;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
                webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
                display:block; 
                white-space: pre-wrap;  
                white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
                white-space: -pre-wrap; 
                white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
                word-wrap: break-word; 
                width:100%; overflow-x:auto;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // Enabling error reporting
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

        require_once __DIR__ . '/firebase.php';
        require_once __DIR__ . '/push_firebase.php';

        $firebase = new Firebase();
        $push = new Push();

        // optional payload
        $payload = array();
        $payload['team'] = 'India';
        $payload['score'] = '5.6';

        // notification title
        $title = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '';

        // notification message
        $message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : '';

        // push type - single user / topic
        $push_type = isset($_GET['push_type']) ? $_GET['push_type'] : '';

        // whether to include to image or not
        $include_image = isset($_GET['include_image']) ? TRUE : FALSE;


        $push->setTitle($title);
        $push->setMessage($message);
        if ($include_image) {
            $push->setImage('http://api.androidhive.info/images/minion.jpg');
        } else {
            $push->setImage('');
        }
        $push->setIsBackground(FALSE);
        $push->setPayload($payload);


        $json = '';
        $response = '';

        if ($push_type == 'topic') {
            $json = $push->getPush();
            $response = $firebase->sendToTopic('global', $json);
        } else if ($push_type == 'individual') {
            $json = $push->getPush();
            $regId = isset($_GET['regId']) ? $_GET['regId'] : '';
            $response = $firebase->send($regId, $json);
        }
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="fl_window">
                <div><img src="http://api.androidhive.info/images/firebase_logo.png" width="200" alt="Firebase"/></div>
                <br/>
                <?php if ($json != '') { ?>
                    <label><b>Request:</b></label>
                    <div class="json_preview">
                        <pre><?php echo json_encode($json) ?></pre>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <br/>
                <?php if ($response != '') { ?>
                    <label><b>Response:</b></label>
                    <div class="json_preview">
                        <pre><?php echo json_encode($response) ?></pre>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="get">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Send to Single Device</legend>

                    <label for="redId">Firebase Reg Id</label>
                    <input type="text" id="redId" name="regId" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Enter firebase registration id">

                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Enter title">

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Notification message!"></textarea>

                    <label for="include_image" class="pure-checkbox">
                        <input name="include_image" id="include_image" type="checkbox"> Include image
                    </label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="push_type" value="individual"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary btn_send">Send</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>

            <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="get">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Send to Topic `global`</legend>

                    <label for="title1">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title1" name="title" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Enter title">

                    <label for="message1">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" name="message" id="message1" rows="5" placeholder="Notification message!"></textarea>

                    <label for="include_image1" class="pure-checkbox">
                        <input id="include_image1" name="include_image" type="checkbox"> Include image
                    </label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="push_type" value="topic"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary btn_send">Send to Topic</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result that I have gotten:

Request:

```
{"data":{"title":"This is a second test from php","is_background":false,"message":"Second test from php","image":"","payload":{"team":"India","score":"5.6"},"timestamp":"2017-02-28 3:05:55"}}
```

Response:

```
"{\"message_id\":5384787464945132888}"
```

I couldn't find which part went wrong. Does anyone knows what went wrong?

Edited:
push_firebase.php

```
public function getPush() {
        $res = array();
        $res['notification']['title'] = $this->title;
        //$res['data']['is_background'] = $this->is_background;
        //$res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
        //$res['data']['image'] = $this->image;
        //$res['data']['payload'] = $this->data;
        //$res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        return $res;
    }
```

firebase.php

```
// sending push message to single user by firebase reg id
    public function send($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $to,
            'notification' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // Sending message to a topic by topic name
    public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
            'notification' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // sending push message to multiple users by firebase registration ids
    public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $registration_ids,
            'notification' => $message,
        );

        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }
```

Request:

```
{"notification":{"title":"test"}}
```

Response:

```
"{\"message_id\":5724949249510866740}"
```

Android code onMessageReceived:

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Log.e(TAG,"FROM: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage == null){
            return;
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //check if message contains a data payload
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.e(TAG,"Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,"Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your edited script, you were only adding a title, but in your Android side code, you're only handling the notification body. Try [`handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification.html#getTitle()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response shows a `message_id` which means the request *is* successful.

Did you mean to point out that you weren't able to receive the notification? If so, then this is probably because you were using a `data` message payload while your Android code is only handling `notification` message payloads. See [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for the description of both.

Push notifications coming from the Firebase Console are classified as `notification` message payloads. When you add in custom key-value pairs in the *Advanced Options*, it'll become a combination of both (`notification` and `data` in a single payload).

To handle `data`-*only* payloads, you'll have to use [`RemoteMessage.getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()). See [Handling Messages in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) for more details.

Comment: how should I modify these PHP scripts ?

Comment: In your scripts you were using `'data'`. You can choose to use `'notification'` instead. Do keep in mind that `notification` payloads only have pre-defined parameters available. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: I have edited my scripts as above but still doesn't get any notification

Comment: Are you still receiving a `message_id` in the response? Can you post your Android side code?

Comment: It's pretty long but its pretty much the same as the tutorial in the link I highlighted above.

Comment: The code snippet for `onMessageReceived()` should be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be something like this for Android then it will work like a charm.

```
'registration_ids' => array (
                $api_key
        ),
        'notification' => array (
               "title" => "Title",
                "body" => "Body"
        )
```